# Getting collection issue in observer Magento

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, collection

I want to sort the customer attribute address after `sort_order`. For some reason by default it doesn't work so I started to digging into the core. This function :

```
protected function _getFormAttributeCollection()
{
   return parent::_getFormAttributeCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('neq' => 'created_at'));
}
```

from `Mage_Customer_Model_Form` is responsible . If I add here this code `->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC');` to my collection its working fine. Due to the fact that  you don't touch the core, I want to fix this from an observer.
I used this event: `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` and this is my function from my observer:

```
 $grid = $observer->getBlock();
 if ($grid instanceof  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element) {
   $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
   $collection = $collection->getSelect()->order('sort_order', 'ASC');
// $collection->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC');
   $observer->getEvent()->setCollection($collection);
 }
```

The fact is that $collection is always null. I don't know why ?  Can someone give me an idea how to fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` is too broad, it's called every time a block is rendered. 
Even though you have a condition in your observer, it's still to broad, the collection is there, you are probably just looking at some other block that is loading on that page.

## Solution:

Override `Mage_Customer_Model_Form` and add

```
return parent::_getFormAttributeCollection() 
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('neq' => 'created_at'))
    ->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC');
```

To the `_getFormAttributeCollection()` method.

Comment: It is about this collection `Mage::getResourceModel('customer/form_attribute_collection')` . IF you check that function that I mentioned `_getFormAttributeCollection` in the core.

Comment: If i use your collection I still get the wrong sorting order for my customer address attributes.

Comment: If I use this `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/form_attribute_collection')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSort('sort_order', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);`    Im getting this message: `Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Form_Attribute_Collection::getCollection()`

Comment: `Mage::getResourceModel('customer/form_attribute_collection')` returns a collection, so you don't need the `->getCollection()`

Try using:

`$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/form_attribute_collection')->addAttributeToSort('sort_order', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);`

But again, don't use the observer you created, it will be called way to often for what you're trying to achieve, override the block where the collection is called.

Comment: Or you can just override  `Mage_Customer_Model_Form` and add `->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC');` to `return parent::_getFormAttributeCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('neq' => 'created_at'));`

Comment: yep, That is what I did, I didn't find anyway to do it from an observer :)

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the solution, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$addressAttributeCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_attribute_collection');
$addressAttributeCollection->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC');
```

Comment: nothing happens :)  with or without this code: `$observer->getEvent()->setCollection($addressAttributeCollection);` still got the wrong sorting type .